# Active Directory Authentication with .NET Core Web API and React

Tags: reactjs, authentication, active-directory, .net-core, ldap

I don't know if I'm just not looking in the right places, but I cannot seem to find  the right guidance on where to begin working with React / .NET Core 2.1 Web API and (on-prem) Active Directory authentication.

I'm relatively new to .NET authentication in general, and completely new to Active Directory authentication.

I started by using the .NET Core 2.1 React template and attempting to add auth to it, but got completely lost.

Where do I even start?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For me, step one was to **set up JWT authentication**, [such as described in this MSDN blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/04/06/jwt-validation-and-authorization-in-asp-net-core/).

Next, I had to **find a library to use to check a user against Active Directory**. [I chose System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement/) (available for .NET Core).

Now, I had to **create a new controller** with an `[AllowAnonymous]`attribute. I called it `LoginController`, and created an action that looked like the following:

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    // Notice: We get a custom request object from the body
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody] AuthRequest request)
    {
            // Create a context that will allow you to connect to your Domain Controller
            using (var adContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "mydomain.com"))
            {
                    var result = adContext.ValidateCredentials(request.username, request.password);
                    if (result)
                    {
                        // Create a list of claims that we will add to the token. 
                        // This is how you can control authorization.
                        var claims = new[]
                        {
                            // Get the user's Name (this can be whatever claims you wish)
                            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, request.username)
                        };

                        // Read our custom key string into a a usable key object 
                        var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(configuration.GetSection("SOME_TOKEN").Value));
                        // create some signing credentials using out key
                        var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

                        // create a JWT 
                        var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                            issuer: "mydomain.com",
                            audience: "mydomain.com",
                            claims: claims, // the claims listed above
                            expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30), // how long you wish the token to be active for
                            signingCredentials: creds);

                        Since we return an IActionResult, wrap the token inside of a status code 200 (OK)
                        return Ok(new
                        {
                            token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token)
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        // if we haven't returned by now, something went wrong and the user is not authorized
        return Unauthorized();
    }
```

The `AuthRequest` object could look something like this:

```
    public class AuthRequest
    {
        public string username { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }
    }
```

Now, in my React app, all I have to do is **make a simple fetch request** to the `LoginController` with the user's username & password that I can get from a login form. The result will be a JWT I can save to state (But should save to cookies: [the `react-cookie` library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-cookie) makes that trivial).

```
        fetch(`login`, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'application/json',
                'accept': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({this.state.username, this.state.password})
        }).then((response) => {
            if (response.status === 401) {
                // handle the 401 gracefully if this user is not authorized
            }
            else {
                // we got a 200 and a valid token
                response.json().then(({ token }) => {
                    // handle saving the token to state/a cookie
                })
            }
        })
```

You now have the ability to add the `[Authorize]` attribute to any of your controllers in your .NET Core application, and **make a fetch request** to it while **passing your JWT** from your React client, like this:

```
await fetch(`someController/someAction`, 
  {  
      method: 'GET'
      headers: {
          'content-type': 'application/json',
          'authorization': `Bearer ${YOUR_JWT}`
      }
  })
  .then(response => doSomething());
```

If you wanted to **use this JWT with a SignalR** `Hub`, add the `[Authorize]` attribute to your `Hub` in your .NET Core project. Then, In your React client, when you instantiate the connection to your hub:

```
import * as signalR from '@aspnet/signalr';

var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl('myHub', { accessTokenFactory: () => YOUR_JWT })
```

**And, viola!** A .NET Core React application capable of authorized real-time communication!

Comment: Perfect answer. Valid still for 2022 and NET6 (with slight change on server side - instead of `app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication`, NET6 uses `.AddJwtBearer`. Thank you.