# AD authentication in JS or .NET Core?

Tags: javascript, .net-core, active-directory, azure-iot-hub

I have a web application that is a single page Javascript (ReactJS) application with a .NET Core backend. I want to add Active Directory authentication and the Azure portal gives several choices, most noticeably signing in with Javascript or .NET Core.

In my situation, which should I choose and why?

My .NET Core code contacts the Azure IoT Hub, if that's any help to decide which way to go.

Comment: Anyone? ........

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion , you should create a Login controller in your Dot net core solution where you should write your authentication and authorization feature. Here is how the complete flow would look like:

- Create a new controller with an attribute ,call it **`LoginController`**, with login and other functionality . Protect it with Azure AD ( you will find many sources for the same)
- Create a React app , which would internally raise a Fetch request to your controller for authentication.
- Once the above request is completed successfully, store the JWT base token in session storage or in cookies.
- Use the stored JWT token , for all you consecutive call

Please check below link for additional reference:

[Active Directory Authentication with .NET Core Web API and React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52104413/active-directory-authentication-with-net-core-web-api-and-react)

[Authentication in .net Core with ReactJS SPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56361859/authentication-in-net-core-with-reactjs-spa?rq=1)

Hope it helps.